# SDK for pdf sticky slip and text highlighter IOS

Tags: ios, pdf, sdk

I need to integrate the pdf reader in my application, In that I need to add sticky notes and highlighting the text I have gone through examples like fast pdf kit and iannotate pdf, But it is very expensive for me to go with it. Please suggest any SDK build with a free library and how can implement this?

Comment: https://github.com/vfr/Reader I used it. It can search and highlight.

Comment: this is theory: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf_scan/dq_pdf_scan.html

Comment: @stosha thanks for reply,i have used vfr/Reader,in this i can't able to highlight the text i can able to read and bookmark the pdf file.